# Can a person be described as "large"?

Tags: word-usage

A non-native English speaker asked me whether referring to a person as "large" was "normal". Eg. That guy is large! It sounded odd to me so I said *I* wouldn't. Is there a rule about this? Eg It's only used for objects and not humans? Or is my hunch wrong?

Comment: Semantics don't really have ‘rules’ as such; we can only say what's in common usage and likely to be understood. Describing a person as ‘large’ is perhaps not as common as describing them as ‘big’, but it's obvious what it means (depending on context). “He was a large, broad-shouldered man” sounds perfectly normal to me, though “He is large” sounds unusual.

Comment: "Ngrams not found: guy is large" (vs. guy is **huge**)

Comment: It's sometimes a euphemism for fat, but it's a suitable usage.

Comment: A 'large guy' rather than ''that guy is large' - still correct, but a tad unwieldly.

Comment: Normally one would say "big guy" rather than "large guy", but there's nothing wrong with the latter.  ("Big guy" is about 200 times more common than "large guy" on Ngram, and I'll note that "large guy" seems a better choice in a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AxSXQa4HH0C&pg=PT157&dq=%22large+guy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGlMn3_MnPAhVG54MKHXAjASEQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22large%20guy%22&f=false) that's discussing the nature of the muscular body: *but the muscle or fat on a large guy may absorb the shock and dissipate the energy through out all that body mass.*

Comment: Sure, perfectly fine if describing a large man. He may be tall, muscular, etc. without being fat. The Rock (Dwayne Johnson) is without a doubt a large man compared to most of us ordinary mortals. Could also mean fat, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

**You can describe a person as large, and be in good company, although be careful!**

From [The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/105843?rskey=5CtGoQ&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> e. Of a person.
>
> (a) Greater than average in size of body and limbs; well-built. In
>   later use sometimes euphem.: overweight, fat. the larger lady:
>   overweight women as a class
>
> 1729   ‘C. Fell’ Lives of Saints IV. 300   As he was large and strong
>   he undertook more Work than most of his Brethren.
>
> 1836   Dickens Pickwick Papers (1837) ii. 15   A large lady in blue
>   satin.
>
> 1870   Dickens Edwin Drood vi. 36   ‘Is he a large man, Ma?’ ‘I should
>   call him a large man, my dear..but that his voice is so much larger’.
>
> 1905   Titusville (Pa.) Herald 17 Apr. 7/1 (advt.)    For the larger
>   lady a nice full skirt pattern.
>
> 1922   Amer. Cloak & Suit Rev. Dec. 119/3   No capable saleswoman ever
>   asks a large woman what size she wears.
>
> 1947   B. Mason in Landfall Dec. 284   Among us Kiwis he was large
>   certainly, but beside the boys from Bolton and Leeds, he looked like a
>   bear with his cubs.
>
> 2002   Big Issue 4 Nov. 29/4   Once a fun-sized beacon of hope for the
>   larger lady, Missy done gone shed more pounds than a dotcom
>   shareholder

To bring the usage up to 2016, it is not hard to imagine the following (made up)

> It was a horrible flight.  I had a middle seat and was sandwiched
>   between a very large woman on my left and a very large man on my
>   right.

As the quotations from the OED suggest, anyone hearing this would probably assume that the woman was fat.  As for the man -- he might be fat or he might be 6'4" and 250 pounds of pure muscle.  Unfair!

A very common usage of **large** is in referring to size, as in the following conversation I had with a large muscular friend at my gym, for whom I was going to buy a T-shirt

> Q: What size should I get?
>
> A: I'm an extra extra large.

Thus, you could call someone "an extra large", obliquely referring to his T-shirt size or his sweat-pants size.

This is flattering if it's a man, and his size comes from muscle, not fat.  Women's sizes also come in large, extra large and so on, but don't call a woman large.

For **large** referring to size, [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/large)

> 8a size of garments for persons who are heavier or broader than
>   average.
>
> 8b.  a garment in this size